# JQuery.setText() max length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, limit

thanks for taking the time to read this post.

I have been looking online for the past little while and cannot find what I want I keep finding how to set a max length, I need to know if there IS a max length allowed to be set through using the `Jquery.text();` funciton?

I am trying to set the text through using this function but it is limiting me somewhere around 500 characters?

I need to display text well over 3000 characters (a full length blog post).

I have tried using the `.innerHMTL = data;` but it does the same thing.

How can I remove this limit if there is? Or what is going on?

Thanks so much!

**UPDATE**

I have figured out that there is no limit to the amount of characters, however when I have a line break or something in the article/blog post recorded in the database, it won't show. ie: i can have this:

```
soihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdj.bakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujh.bakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakaiusdaiujsbhdaiujshbdaisbdlaisjbdlskjfjshtdhsjkchssoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdj.bakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujh.bakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakaiusdaiujsbhdaiujshbdaisbdlaisjbdlskjfjshtdhsjkchssoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdj.bakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujh.bakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakaiusdaiujsbhdaiujshbdaisbdlaisjbdlskjfjshtdhsjkchssoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdj.bakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujh.bakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakaiusdaiujsbhdaiujshbdaisbdlaisjbdlskjfjshtdhsjkchs
```

BUT if I have even one 'enter' or line break like this:

```
s
oihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdj.bakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujh.bakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakaiusdaiujsbhdaiujshbdaisbdlaisjbdlskjfjshtdhsjkchssoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdj.bakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujh.bakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakaiusdaiujsbhdaiujshbdaisbdlaisjbdlskjfjshtdhsjkchssoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdj.bakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujh.bakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakaiusdaiujsbhdaiujshbdaisbdlaisjbdlskjfjshtdhsjkchssoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdj.bakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujh.bakjsbndjkasoihdkjbasdjbakjsnbdiujhaskjdbakaiusdaiujsbhdaiujshbdaisbdlaisjbdlskjfjshtdhsjkchs`
```

it wont show. What the heck is going on??
Can some one please explain it?

Thanks for your patience and understanding (I am 17 years old, and not to clued up on stuff this advanced)

here is the code that calls the method:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $data =  $post['data'];
            echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="getContent(\'#content\', \''. $data .'\');">'.$post['date_for_post'] .'</a></li>';
        }
```

and here is the method itself:

```
function getContent(element, data){
$(element).text(data);
}
```

I have also tried adding in `$(element).attr('maxlength', '3000');` and changing the `.text()` to `.html()` and `.innerHTML = data`

Comment: What kind of element you want to text()? If it's just a text input with "maxlength" attribute, try $(ele).removeAttr('maxlength');

Comment: There is no limit i'm aware of. Are you sure data is what you expect it to be? Please provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff I cannot use jsfiddle as it uses a database file and I am not familiar with jsfiddle enough for that

Comment: @Andrew I have realized that there is no limit to the amount of characters, but if I have a line break or something in the post in the database, then it wont show at all?

Comment: @VaMoose There must be something specific going on. We should know more about your code to be able to find out the problem. Details, details, details. `.text()` works well, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Plesae see the updated post

Comment: damn, he's right !!! Putting a line break in the text you want to `.text()` gives a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/C6UBC/.  But, if you remove all line break, it works http://jsfiddle.net/rPLgp/.  I suggest replace all `\n \r` occurence by a `<br/>` and use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. demo here http://jsfiddle.net/rPLgp/1/ . Anyway, there is no length limitation.

Comment: @VaMoose Are you adding that data into a `textbox` or `textarea'

Comment: @BharathRallapalli I am adding it to a div, I do not want the people to be able to edit it

Comment: @VaMoose The error is in the string literal , try replacing all `\n` in the string in the server itself and then pass it to client side.

Comment: @BharathRallapalli there is no `\n` in the script, what I pasted was raw data from the db. there are literally 'enter's' and no `\n`

Comment: @VaMoose But if you store that in a string , all the enters will be '\n'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41968/discussion-between-bharath-rallapalli-and-vamoose)